# How to solve this integral? This notation is strange

Tags: calculus, integration

$\int_{(1,1,1}^{(x,y,\frac{1}{xy})} \frac{yzdx +xzdy+xydz}{xyz}  $= ??

What does these points of $\mathbb{R}^3 $ mean at the integration extremes?

What is the meaning of this and why do the integral variables appear in the extremes?

Answer (score 1):

$$\int_{(1,1,1)}^{(x,y,\frac{1}{xy})} \frac{yzdx +xzdy+xydz}{xyz}$$
can be interpreted as $$\int_{(1,1,1)}^{(x,y,\frac{1}{xy})} \frac{dx}{x}+\frac{dy}{y}+\frac{dz}{z}$$
now integrate:
$$[\ln(x)+\ln(y)+ln(z)+\ln(c)]$$
$$=\ln(xyzc)$$
put limits: let $$y=\ln(xyzc)$$
$$y(x,y,\frac 1 {xy})=\ln(xy\frac 1 {xy} c)=\ln(c)$$
$$y(1,1,1)=\ln(1\cdot1\cdot1\cdot c)=\ln(c)$$

$$y(x,y,\frac{1}{xy})-y(1,1,1)=\ln(c)-\ln(c)=0$$
So, solution of this integral is $0$